# Date sorting issue with ultimate date time sorting Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, datatables, momentjs

I'm having trouble with the sorting of a date column. 
I'm using datatables with moment.js. But the dates aren't beeing sorted right.

It seems that it only sorts the day but not the year.

I've made a jsfiddle with the issue if you sort the startdate there are records of 2019 between records of 2020

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obswu4tk/)

Any idea's of what is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks cнŝdk, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

By default it sorts the data as strings. You can change the dates format to `YYYY-MM-DD` then default sorting will give you what you need. Or you can redefine sorting algorithm for the "Start date" column so that it compares values as dates, not as strings.